# Если я использую прокси на работе, увидит ли мой трафик сис-админ?

Tags: proxy

Дает ли пользование он-лайн прокси сервером (к примеру kproxy) гарантию, что трафик через него не будет доступен для просмотра сиc-админом (к примеру, на работе)?

Сам то прокси обещает, что соединение шифруется ...

> 100% safe Proxy encrypts the connection between your browser to your
>   target server

Comment: Прокси нет, vpn да.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Использование прокси даёт гарантию, что трафик при желании *может быть* просмотрен сисадмином. Трафик между клиентом и прокси *не шифруется* и, следовательно, легко просматривается. Более того, юзер, использующий прокси, легко "палится", поскольку почти весь его трафик идёт на один внешний адрес, что обычно подозрительно и привлекает к себе внимание.

Гарантию от прослушки дают только шифрованные соединения, например, VPN.

Comment: Зашифрованное соединение тем более с одним и тем же внешним адресом ни у сисадмина, ни у безопасника никаких подозрений не вызывает и вызывать не может.

Comment: @banme Ну-ну...

Comment: Ну-ну себе адресуйте. Ведь именно Вы и утверждаете, что благодаря VPN будет всё ништяк. А если в конторе жёсткие требования к секурити, то несанкционированный зашифрованный трафик говорит скорее о промышленном шпионаже. Такого шпиёна быстро вычисляют по ип и ликвидируют (иногда физически:) вместе с его VPN. В общем объяснятся придётся зачем, куда, что сливается в зашифрованном виде.

Comment: @banme Чукча не читатель, чукча - писатель? Покажите мне то место, где я утверждаю что всё будет "ништяк"? Читайте внимательнее: "Гарантию от ***прослушки*** дают только шифрованные соединения".

Comment: От прослушки гарантию может и дают, но не надолго. Сам же под пытками СБ всё и расшифруешь.

Comment: @banme От паяльника никто не застрахован. Особенно в России.

Comment: Https тоже ведь шифруется, но ведь в нормальных конторах за это не ставят на "карандаш". А вот большой трафик с одним и тем же адресом - да, заставляет задуматься.

Answer (score 0):

Существует такая технология, как [VPN](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPN), позволяющая объединить компьютеры в одну логическую сеть поверх сети Интернет. Причем соединение шифруется от Вашего компьютера до VPN сервера, поэтому системные администраторы не смогут смотреть Ваш трафик. Так что если хотите побездельничать на работе, смотрите в эту сторону =)